# Incorrect shadows from point light

Tags: unity-game-engine

When a light source (point light) is close to any object, a strange glare appears on it. I noticed that this problem is related to the parameter Near Plane, if I put it to a value of 1.6 or more, then the glare disappears, but then the shadows from objects within a certain radius are not displayed, is there a way to save the shadows and remove the glare?

[Glare Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIAiU.jpg)

[Point light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uceN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just increased the bias parameter to 0.032 and the glare disappeared.